# Count Number SQL where not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there an option to get numbers where not in exist in the Table?

Example

```
product_number
1
2
3
5
```

I want only the number 4 as result, because it's a free product number.
The Problem is with connect by rownum doesn't work, because out of memory.

Comment: How many numbers do you want to check?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select coalesce(min(product_number), 0) + 1
from (select t.*, lead(product_number) over (order by product_number) as next_pn
      from t
     ) t
where next_pn <> product_number + 1;
```

Oracle will use an index on `(product_number)` if one is available.

Comment: I want a range of numbers and want as return all of them, is there an option?

Comment: @KleeSchulz . . . I would suggest you ask a new question.  This question gives as an example only finding one value.  That gives the impression that you only want one number ( as well as the use of the singular in the title).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Select Rownum r -- Generate all numbers from 1 to max
From dual
Connect By Rownum <= (select max(product_number) from products)
where r not in 
(
  select product_number from products
)
```

Comment: Yes like this, but i get all the time the message not enough memory space

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide sample of real product numbers (apparently) but claim connect by runs out of memory could imply you have very large product numbers.
So restricting the numbers that need checked needs to be reduced to the range known to potentially existing, that being the min and max product numbers. Once that's known we can generate the the index on product number to see if the specific number exists, or in this doesn't exist. So:

```
with lh  as 
     (select min(product_number) l  
           , max(product_number) h 
       from products
     )  
   , range (pn) as
      (select product_number pn 
         from products 
        where product_number = (select l from lh)
       union all 
       select pn + 1 
         from range 
        where pn + 1 <= (select h from lh)
      )  
select pn available_product_number
  from range
 where not exists
     ( select null 
       from products
      where pn = product_number
     )
order by pn;
```